# Mule: SMTP endpoint full mailto: instead of to, subject attributes

Tags: java, mule

I have access to a string for an smtp endpoint that looks like this:
mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com

I could parse the string to extract the to, and subject attributes and use those with my smtp endpoint, however, I bet there is just a way to pass this whole string to the endpoint, but I haven't found it. I have tried using the address attribute, but it expects an smtp://[host]:[port] URI, so I'm not sure it could be used for this.

Has anyone succeeded in passing a valid mailto: URI to the Mule SMTP endpoint?

If this doesn't work, then I'll need to parse the string, I could use android.net.MailTo, which is a class that parses a mailto: URI, as an alternative, if no tool is available from Mule to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use %40 instead of @  ... There is no other way to parse this I guess 
example :- aka11@gmail.com can be written as aka11%40gmail.com

Comment: Yes, I urlencode the string, but this still doesn't tell me how I can pass the whole mailto string to the smtp endpoint, instead of parsing it and breaking it apart into several attributes.

Comment: You need to put %40 instead of @ ... I don't don't think there is any other ways as Mule unable to parse @ ... so use %40 instead of @

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

On the flow:

```
<outbound-endpoint address="${alertmail.address}" doc:name="Generic4">
    <properties>
        <spring:entry key="subject" value="${alertemail.subject}" />
    </properties>
</outbound-endpoint>
```

And on the properties file (replacing **mailserver**, **user** and **domain** by proper values):

```
alertmail.address=smtp://mailserver?address=user@domain
```

Copied the structure of the URI from here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/SMTP+Transport